# how to reset a static variable inside a post delayed handler in android

Tags: android, static, handler

I have a loop of 5 everytime a user clicks 5 textview are created an added to parent view. But if i click the button continously (like before the previos look stop) then the temp value surpases the 0 to 4 and goes on.... how can i reset the temp value (static variable) inside an handler.

```
      // start of program.
         static int temp = 0;

      // button on click event
         temp = 0;

                        for(k = 0; k < 5; k++){
                          new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {  
                                    Animation a1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.00f, 1.00f);
                                    a1.setDuration(350);
                                    a1.setFillAfter(true);  
                                    TextView tv = new TextView(Main.this);  
                                    tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 

                                //  tv.setText(emotionnames.get(temp));  //crashing here. index is 5 size is 5


                                    Log.i("temp", Integer.toString(temp));  
                                    tv.setTextSize(32); 
                                    tv.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
                                    tv.clearAnimation();   
                                    tv.startAnimation(a1);
                                    lhsv.addView(tv); 

                                    temp++;
                                }
                            }, 500 + 500 * k);   
                    }
```

Comment: like making it to zero temp = 0

Comment: Not 100% sure what you want, but I modified my example, to give an indication of a possible way to go! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I modified my answer. In general, I think it would be good to add more structure to the class vs doing everything in one place. One of such examples might be like the following:

```
public class StackoverflowActivity extends Activity {

    private Button mBtn;
    private LinearLayout mContainer;

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler()
    {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        int index = msg.what;
        addTextViewAnimated(index);
    }
    };


    // Called when the add-button is clicked
    private OnClickListener myClickListener = new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Create 5 textViews
            for(int k=0; k < 5; k++)
            {
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(k, 500 + 500 * k);
            }
        }

    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Container view -> the linearlayout inside a scrollview
        mContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

        // The button to click
        mBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

        // Add the clicklistener
        mBtn.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);

    }

    // This function creates the TextView
    // And adds it to the container Animated
    public void addTextViewAnimated(int index)
    {
        Animation a1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.00f, 1.00f);
        a1.setDuration(350);
        a1.setFillAfter(true);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        tv.setTextSize(32);
        tv.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
        tv.clearAnimation();
        tv.startAnimation(a1);
        tv.setText("Textview "  + index);
        mContainer.addView(tv);
    }
}
```

For ease of use, here's my main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/btn" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Maybe this will get you started. I'm not exactly sure, what you want to achieve.

Comment: Actully you cant do this as k is in outer class, and thus we have to make it final and if we make it final it wont increment.